# How to use .env in react js

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, package.json

How to use .env in react . I can get access to .env.development and .env.production with

```
 "start":"react-scripts start",
 "build": "react-scripts build",
```

How to get access to another like .env.staging ?

I gave like this

```
"build_staging": "set REACT_APP_ENV=staging & react-scripts build",
```

but not working.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: I am using mac, but it should work for windows also.

Comment: I've added an answer please see if that helps, also upvote and accept if it does :)

Answer (score 5):

To keep things consistent across linux(my production server) and windows(my development server) I use cross-env

> npm install --save cross-env

and my scripts look like this

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production next build ",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server"
  },
```

so to set a custom env like REACT_APP_ENV you'll need to

```
"build_staging": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=staging react-scripts build",
```

and you can access it in your javascript code using

> process.env.REACT_APP_ENV

also to start a staging server you might want to add

> "start_staging": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=staging react-scripts start"

more about this [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables)

Comment: It is taking development even after giving this -> "build_staging": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=staging react-scripts build",

Comment: you might need to add it while starting the app too like
"start": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=staging react-scripts start",

Comment: Yeah you need to add to your start script or better add a new script like

"start_staging": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=staging react-scripts start",

to start a staging server.

Comment: Build_staging command is not working ,it is showing as development only.  start_staging is showing as staging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171744/discussion-between-goutham-and-supra28).

Answer (score 0):

**[CONTEXT]**
 - I've created React project with `Create React`.
 - Running on Windows 10
 - Using VSCode IDE
 - I have the file `.env.development` on above `/src` folder.
 - My code has `console.log(process.NODE_ENV)` and `console.log(process.REACT_APP_YOUR_KEY)`

---

**[PROBLEM]**
When I'm running the program with `npm start`, the browser prints 'development' for `NODE_ENV`, but for my React .env variable, it prints `undefined`.

I try to run `npm start` with changing the default script of `package.json` to this `start` script: `set REACT_APP_YOUR_KEY && react-scripts start`. Then there isn't any `undefined`, all works well.

---

**[SOLUTION]**
The cause was that the file `.env.development` is not detected correctly. My hypothesis is the environment development file, Windows or VSCode don't detect well.

[Windows File Explorer files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz5xJ.png)

[VS Code explorer. Look up the icon of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vlew.png)

You have to change the file name from `.env.development` to `.env`.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLUTION]: I've created env.js as shown below.
[env.js placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQB66.png)

after that i have added in index.html the script below

[my env.js content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vnpx.png)

NB: i can acces my env.js var without import them (it seems the best way for me)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please do not post code images copy/past the code in the answer for a better lisibility